# Process for waiting for method response without blocking other HTTP requests

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code for a HTTP GET method:

```
@Override
public Cert get(Representation entity) {
    // ...
    Cert cert = ct.fetchCertificate(Arrays.asList(domains));
    return cert; 
}
```

It's a certificate generator that returns the serialized `Cert` object into the client.

And inside the `fetchCertificate` method is a `Thread.sleep` method that causes the entire servlet/web application to halt until the method returns, causing the whole web application not able to response to additional HTTP requests:

```
// Poll for the challenge to complete.
try {
       int attempts = 20;
       while (challenge.getStatus() != Status.VALID && attempts-- > 0) {
       LOG.info("CHALLENGE ATTEMPTS: " + attempts);
       // Did the authorization fail?
       if (challenge.getStatus() == Status.INVALID) {
          throw new AcmeException("Challenge failed... Giving up.");
       }

       // Wait for a few seconds
       Thread.sleep(5000L);

       // Then update the status
       challenge.update();
     }
 } catch(Exception e) { 
      // ... 
 }
```

In *RxJava* terms what is the best way to achieve this same functionality but without blocking the application.

Comment: Main question aside, I'd wonder how your *entire web application* would be halted just because one thread sleeps. Is the application single-threaded?

Comment: I'm using Restlet Framework running on NGINX Unit, and I also wonder why it happens. The web app works fine, can do HTTP methods but when this method with `Thread.sleep` gets triggered until it finishes any HTTP request either wait or timeout.

Comment: Maybe you need to configure the size of the thread pool used by your web container. If it's using a single thread, that's already too bad (for a servlet application). For me, that's the first change needed here. Beside that, you may need to use or make an asynchronous API for `challenge.update()` or this method, so that web container threads don't get stuck waiting for your execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this Whole HTTP request calling and sleep inside a secondary thread. It seems it blocks the main thread.

Comment: The method `public Cert get(Representation entity)` is the actual HTTP request method. Not sure what you mean by "put the Whole HTTP request"

Comment: One way would be to create a separate class which would inherit from Thread, and call this get... method from run method

Comment: The same thing will happen if this `fetchCertificate` blocks the web application gets blocked